# Mesonbuild: add dependency using a path

Tags: build, dependency-management, monorepo, meson-build

I have a monorepo-like file structure in a project that is like this:

```
--src
 |__lib1
    |_meson.build
 |__lib2
    |_meson.build
```

`lib1` is built independently, but `lib2` depends on `lib1` (it should be linked to `lib1`).

I hoped that the `dependency` function accepts a `path` argument, but it doesn't support this.

```py
# lib2 meson.build
lib1_dep = dependency('lib1', path: '../lib1')
```

How can I do this in mesonbuild without breaking my project structure?

I prefer not to use a top-level monolith mesonbuild file.

Comment: Opened an issue for this: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/9050

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a `dependency` for this, `dependency()` is for *external* dependencies. You have two options:

The first is to use `link_with`:

```
lib2 = library(
  'lib2',
  lib2_sources,
  link_with : lib1
)
```

This disadvantage of this is that if you need headers you need to pass include paths to the `include_paths` argument.

The better way is to use `declare_dependenc()`, which allows you to create *internal* dependencies:

lib1/meson.build:

```
lib1 = library(...)
dep1 = declare_dependency(link_with : lib1, include_directories : include_directories('.'))
```

lib2/meson.build:

```
lib2 = library(
  'lib2',
  lib2_sources,
  dependencies : dep1,
)
```